# session when ajax call to nodejs with apache mod_proxy and from a different domain

Tags: ajax, node.js, apache, cookies, express

So i've created an apache proxy to forward my api.example.loc to localhost:8080/api

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.loc
ServerName api.example.loc

ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/api/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/api/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
</Location>
```

and i'm having my nodejs server running and listening on port 8080

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),

app
.use(require('cookie-parser')())
.use(require('express-session')({ secret: 's£cr£+c@d£' }))
.get('/api', function(req, res) {
    var host = req.get('host');

    console.log(host);
    console.log(req.sessionID);
});

server.listen(8080);
```

when calling localhost:8080 or api.example.loc everything is okay
i'm having the host api.example.loc && the same sessionID when refreshing

```
api.example.loc
BWqB8NtZ3beHXZchkxJvwvEB
```

but when trying to call my api.example.loc from an other domain, lets say api.loc using ajax

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://api.livechat.loc/', crossDomain: true });
```

i'm having a new sessionID each time i refresh the page on api.loc

```
api.livechat.loc
OcIGeviXOmCkBWRELzPqMmVu

api.livechat.loc
1yGT3rBaPaf9HCQ5zGd4iUud
```

i've noticed that when calling api.example.come that a session cookie is created on host api.example.loc, but no cookie is created if called through ajax from api.loc, so i've tried the next, with no better results

```
...
.use(require('express-session')({ secret: 's£cr£+c@d£', cookie: { domain: '.api.loc', path: '/', maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 24 } }))
...
```

any ideas ?

Comment: i've changed my ajax call to

$.ajax({ url: 'http://api.livechat.loc/', crossDomain: true, xhrFields: { withCredentials: true } });

and my added the following line to the location section on my proxy

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true

now when ajax call is performed the cookie is created but i'm having a cross domain porblem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i finished by adding withCredentials to my ajax call so cookies can be set cross domain

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://api.livechat.loc/', crossDomain: true, xhrFields: { withCredentials: true } });
```

and changing the location section on my proxy conf to

```
<Location />
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With"
    Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "60"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/api/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/api/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
</Location>
```